# Sending whatsapp messages to a number using the API

Tags: angular, whatsapp

I am trying to send a message to a WhatsApp number from my app built using Angular 4 and Ionic 3 . I am trying this on a button click event. This is my code.

HTML

```
<div padding>
    <button id="addBtn" (click)="WhatsApp()" ion-button color="primary" block>WhatsApp</button>
  </div>
```

TS

```
  WhatsApp(){
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      console.log("Before API")
      this.http.get("https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=121234567891&text=I'm%20interested%20in%20your%20car%20for%20sale").map(response => response.json()).subscribe(data => {
        resolve(data);
        console.log("After API",data)
      }, err => {
      });
    });
  }
```

I want to send a message on the button click. So where must I specify the number from which and number to which I am going to send and is the way I have done is correct? Thanks in advance

Comment: why you want to use us promise and rxjs?

Comment: I am returning outcome of this function to some other function.

Comment: that you can do without promise also.

Comment: So what is your solution for my question?

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: No, But nothing happens